# Batch (X) Key, Want to End Process

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

Is it possible to close the Batch File, like "press any key"?

Because I have made a Batch file, that renames a file. And when I Launch the .Bat file, The File changes name to the desired name. And when I "press any key" I made it so the File changes name back to the normal name.

However When i press the (X) Button, to close the batch. It does not follow the last line of code. To rename the file Back. Only works when I "press any key".

Comment: What do you expect.  You are forcefully terminating the process.

Comment: Like is there a Way, to close it like Press Any Key? When press (X)

Comment: The red X is not part of the running process, it's part of the parent process. When you kill a parent process, the children processes have no idea that they're orphans.

Comment: if you display "press any key" why don't you press any key but click the GUI button?

Comment: "I want my cmd to finish it's work when I close the window" is like "I want my computer to continue running when I remove the power cable"

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're trying to say is that you want the file to change its name so that, when you `press any key` or exit out of the program it goes back to the original name, right?
I do not think this is possible with batch as when you terminate the process, (command prompt in our case) it cannot execute a command as it is closing. What you could do is make the command prompt launch another command prompt on start and make that command prompt wait until the 1st one is closed and then rename the file back and close itself. This is not that practical though. If you are realy desperate however, try this code:

```
@echo off
start "CommandPrompt" cmd.exe /WAIT /K ren OriginalFileName.txt NewFileName.txt & pause>nul & ren NewFileName.txt OriginalFileName.txt
ren NewFileName.txt OriginalFileName.txt
exit
```

While it does essentialy do what you want it to, it relies on the 2 command windows to be closed in order. It is however probably the least complex way out there. It probably goes without saying that you need to replace `OriginalFileName.txt` and `NewFileName.txt` with whatever names you need.